# Java массив: вернуть Object[]

Tags: jdbc, java

Можно ли  методом вернуть Object[]

```
Object[] line = new Object[sm.getColumnCount()];
for (int i = 1; i < sm.getColumnCount(); i++)

line[i--] = rs.getObject(i);

rs.close();
connect.close();
return line[];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по приведенному куску речь идет о JDBC...

1. Из-за конструкции `line[i--]` у вас будет бесконечный цикл. Наверное надо было написать `line[i-1]=rs.getObject(i)`
2. Если встретится поле типа BLOB, то `Recordset.getObject()` выдаст указатель `Blob`, который ссылается  на `InputStream`, который бессмысленно держать в `Object`

**Резюме:** код нерабочий, требуется доработка

Comment: да все разобрался i-- знаю нужно всего лишь line возращать